# React onClick not applying to surrounding area

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following layout in a React component:

```
     <div class="iconButton" onClick={clickEvent}>
        <MyIcon />
      </div>
```

MyIcon is an SVG file that renders out to the screen. When the user hovers over MyIcon, a hover background shows.

However, when you click anywhere except on the icon exactly, the click event does not fire. Why is the click event not firing when the highlighted area around the icon (e.g. the div itself) is clicked?

Comment: Your click event only works on area covered by iconButton div.so check how much area covered by that div

Comment: Can you share your code on codepen or some other online editor?

Comment: add background color to your div so you can see what are does it covers. maybe you've set `display` to `inline-block`

Answer (score 1):

The class contained a `display: inline-block`, as mentioned above. Once removed the click worked correctly